# Hybrid encryption approach fails

Tags: java, security, encryption, aes, rsa

Im having trouble with my attempt to create a small programme using hybrid encryption with AES and RSA. It works just fine using only symmetric encryption AES which i have tried, but when i try to implement RSA to wrap the AES encrypted message and key i just cant get it to work.

I have understood that a programme like this can be done using outputstreams or cipherstreams but I´d like to solve it this way if it is possible. In other words id like a user to enter any string into the JOptionInputDialog and get it encrypted with AES key and then the AES key encrpyted with RSA public key and then decrypted with a private RSA  key.

I want the answer to display in the same JOptionPane window. In example :

The encrypted text : jfjfjh
The decrypted text : Hello

I have issues right now understanding how to get that string decrypted with the private RSA key. I dont know what i am missing or doing wrong. From any examples ive been googling for the past week and a half i think it looks fine. I must be missing something that is right infront of my eyes but i cant see it since i sit up for too many hours trying to find a different approach ( i think ive changed it a million times but i cant show you all my approaches so this is the one i share with you. Id be really thankful for any kind of help. So here is my code: (Hope you can understand as some words are in my language)

```
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author Patricia
 */
public class EncryptionDecryption {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     * @throws java.lang.Exception
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, 
            InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException{

                //Creating assymmetric keys RSA ( A public Key and Private Key )
                KeyPairGenerator gen2 = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
                gen2.initialize(1024);

               KeyPair keyPair = gen2.genKeyPair();
               PrivateKey privatnyckel = keyPair.getPrivate();
               PublicKey publiknyckel = keyPair.getPublic();



              //Create assymmetric key AES //Create key generator
              KeyGenerator gen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES"); //Returns keygenerator object that generates key  for specified algorithm in this case AES

       SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
       gen.init(random);
              // create a key
             SecretKey AES = gen.generateKey();
             //get the raw key bytes
             byte[] symmetriskNyckel =AES.getEncoded(); //Returns copy of the key bytes

              //Create cipher based upon AES, encrypt the message with AES key
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    //Initialize cipher with secret key AES
  cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, AES);

   // get the text to encrypt with AES key
  String inputText1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Enter the secret message");
 //Encrypt the plaintext message you wanna send with the symmetric key AES;
            byte[] kryptera = cipher.doFinal(inputText1.getBytes());

//encrypt AES key with RSA
    Cipher pipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
    pipher.init(Cipher.WRAP_MODE, publiknyckel);
    byte[] krypteradAESNyckel = cipher.wrap(AES); 

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "AES key encrypted with RSA public key " + krypteradAESNyckel);

// re-initialise the cipher to be in decrypt mode 
    Cipher flipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
             flipher.init(Cipher.UNWRAP_MODE, privatnyckel );
 // decrypt message
          byte [] dekryptera =  flipher.unwrap(kryptera);



      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog
        (null, "AES symmetrisk nyckel " +symmetriskNyckel );





    // and display the results // 
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(JOptionPane.getRootFrame(),
                        "Texten krypterad " + new String(kryptera) + "\n"
                                    + "Text dekrypterat: " + new String(dekryptera));




            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "\n RSA assymmetrisk privat nyckel " + privatnyckel
        + "RSA assymmetrisk publik nyckel" + publiknyckel);




            // end example
            System.exit(0);






    }

}
```

Comment: You're never decrypting anything with AES. And instead of unwrapping the wrapped key with RSA, you're unwrapping the AES-encrypted text. Do yourself a favor and 1. indent your code, 2. choose meaningful english names for all your variables, 3. split the code into methods.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As for the english variables, for me its easier to use swedish words as i am in sweden but thanks for the tip :)

Comment: gen and gen2 are probably not swedish words. flipher and pipher neither. And AES is the name of an algorithm. It should be named aesSecretKey, for example. By using ugly, meaningless names, you're making it hard for yourself to read and understand your own code.

Comment: But wait a minute, decrypting with AES? No i want to encrypt it with AES and then encrypt AES key with RSA public key and later on decrypt it with RSA. I said that i tried to just create a programme before using just AES for encryption and decryption which worked fine but now i try to use AES + RSA which fails

Comment: i give you the flipher and pipher but gen and gen2 are meaningless and ugly names? its short for generate and  i think thats pretty clear :)

Comment: You're encrypting text with AES, and encrypting the AES key with RSA. So the reverse operation is to decrypt the encrypted AES key with RSA, and then use that decrypted AES key to decrypt the encrypted text.

Comment: Ok thank you. Its nice to have someone looking at your code and point out what you did wrong. Really appreciate it.

Comment: What is clearer? rsaKeyPairGenerator, or gen? Which is clearer? aesKeyGenerator, or gen2. If you see a variable named `sec` in unknown code, can you guess what it represents? And if you see a variable named `secureRandom`, isn't that much clearer?

Comment: Ok yes you are right. I guess it makes just sense for me as i made the code but yes you are absolutely right.

Comment: I'd like to second @JBNizet. It's somehow funny to see 89 characters of comment which basically describe what can be said with a proper variable name in that context: `aesKeyGenerator` vs. `gen`.

Comment: Im happy my code made you laugh but the comments are needed and have to be many since this is an exersize for school :) and regarding my variables i already admitted they were useless but its good to know beginners amuse the professionals

Comment: Have you seen [SO Help Center's MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) already? In particular the paragraph with "_and_ readable".

Comment: Yes now i have. thanks

Comment: I see, that's comprehensible. This is not your school here, however.

Comment: @Patricia6946 If possible your code should be as self documenting as possible. Comments can easily get out of date. In general I try to use comments on *what* the code is doing, not *how* it is doing it - unless the code is hard to read (e.g. when using regular expressions, optimizations and such).

Comment: Ok @MaartenBodewes i will think about it until next time :) Thanks.
Lets see if i can solve this now, its gettling late here in Sweden :)

Comment: Haarlem is in the same time zone, last time I checked. Good luck and good night, I'm out :)

Comment: You are right :) im so used to talk to Americans when im posting on an other site :) Goodnight and thanks all

Answer (score 1):

I think your variable names and comments are fine to start with. When working with something new, write notes to yourself in the code. You can come back later once it works and refactor with rich, meaningful names, and trim the comments for clarity, so that they speak to you six months or a year from now to remind you of what you were thinking of at the time that you wrote this. (And I think Swedish names are just as good as English.)

As JB Nizet points out, you are unwrapping kryptera when you should be unwrapping the symmetric key contained in krypteradAESNyckel. Next, you would decrypt kryptera with the recovered symmetric key. (Your code justs outputs the earlier symmetriskNyckel without having actually unwrapped it freshly from krypteradAESNyckel.)

I also notice that in one case you

```
Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
```

but later you

```
Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
```

I would make them consistent, both "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding". This attention to detail is just as important as clear variable names and meaningful comments.